# Terraform Pass Variable (Object) to Templatefile

Tags: terraform

I have the following variable that I would like to have rendered in a template file. All values ​​of the variable are optional.

The template itself contains other variables, but these are usually just simple strings.

```
variable "security_context" {
  type = object({
    allow_privilege_escalation = optional(bool)
    read_only_root_filesystem  = optional(bool)
    run_as_non_root            = optional(bool)
    privileged                 = optional(bool)
    capabilities = optional(object({
      add  = optional(list(string))
      drop = optional(list(string))
    }))
  })
  default = null
}

resource "helm_release" "test" {
  ...
  values = [templatefile("${path.module}/values-override.yaml.tpl",
    {
      ...
      sec_context = var.security_context
    }
  )]
}
```

My template file looks like this:

```
%{ if main_container_sec_context != null }
securityContext:
  %{ if sec_context.allow_privilege_escalation != null }
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: ${sec_context.allow_privilege_escalation}
  %{ endif }
  %{ if sec_context.read_only_root_filesystem != null }
  readOnlyRootFilesystem: ${sec_context.read_only_root_filesystem}
  %{ endif }
  %{ if sec_context.run_as_non_root != null }
  runAsNonRoot: ${sec_context.run_as_non_root}
  %{ endif }
  %{ if sec_context.privileged != null }
  privileged: ${sec_context.privileged}
  %{ endif }
%{ endif }
```

For the bool values, this approach works, but it's a lot of code. Can this be reduced by iterating over the values?

What would be the best way to integrate the lists (capabilities: add and drop)?

Comment: You would probably want to approach this from the direction of utilizing `yamlencode` in the template.

Comment: Do you have an example I can look at?